# How do I automate the activation of Python environment

Tags: python, shortcuts

I have created an environment, using `virtualenv`, for Python 3.4.1 which I installed on `/opt`. The environment is on `~/py34`. Every time I want to use it, I have to type:

```
source py34/bin/activate
python
```

Is there anyway to create a shortcut, so that I don't have to type these commands every time I want to use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `~/.bashrc` file, at the end of the file, you can add the `source` line, so that the environment variables are set up when you open a Bash terminal anywhere. Alternatively, you can have it be an alias, as @user74158 has it below in the comments.

You could also have the `python` in there, but note that you will be in the Python shell when you start a Bash terminal and will have to exit out every time you want to get back to Bash.

Comment: I put this on my `~/.bashrc'`: `alias py34="source ~/py34/bin/activate"`. Every time I want to use the Python environment, I just need to type `py34` on terminal.

Comment: That works too.